# jQuery grid that is tiled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was hoping some would know how to tile a grid across. I have some code to get started

```
1 | 2
3 | 4
5 | 6
```

and in my ajax function

```
$.ajax({
  complete:function(result) {
      // in here i want to tile across two sets of td's for each tr
      for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
          $('#products').append('<tr><td>' + products[i].Title + '</td></tr>');
      }
  }
});  
<table id="products"></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works whatever the products size is (even or odd).
Hope with comments make it easy to understand

```
var table_body = '< tbody>';
for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if(i%2==0)//if even we open a row
         table_body += '<tr>';

    //We always put a value  
    table_body += '<td>' + products[i].Title + '</td>';

    if(i%2!=0 || (i==products.length-1))//if odd we close a row
         table_body += '</tr>';

}

table_body += '< /tbody>';
$('#products').append(table_body);
```

Comment: This will miss a closing `<tr>` for an odd number of elements (the last index will be even).

Comment: You are right but I edited it but the changes does not appear, the change is: if(i%2!=0 || (i==products.length-1))

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code of what you are trying to achieve. You can optimize it to suit your needs. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHmYp/)

```
for(var i = 0, y=0; i < 10; i++){

    if(y == 0){
        $('table').html($('table').html() + '<tr>');
    }

    $('table').append('<td>' + i + '</td>')

    y++;

    if( y == 2 ){
        y = 0;
        $('table').html($('table').html() + '</tr>');
    }

}
```

Comment: This will result in invalid markup for an odd number of elements.

Comment: that's why my answer has the **You can optimize it to suit your needs** part.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to simply not use a table. Chances are if you're arranging data this way, it's not tabular data anyway. I recommend using `display: inline-block` on your elements and using an HTML element that makes sense for the data you're using, like a `ul` or `li`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for even or odd numbers of elements, fully tested.

```
var tbl = "";
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) tbl += '<tr>';
    tbl += '<td>' + products[i].Title + '</td>';
    if (i % 2 == 1) tbl += '</tr>';
}
if (i % 2 == 1) tbl += '</tr>';
$("#products").append(tbl);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jli1/VQAak/1/)